# Enable Thread Safety in PHP+Apache2 on Ubuntu - compiling php from source with pthreads

Tags: php, ubuntu, thread-safety, apache2, pthreads

I'm trying to get pthreads running on my Ubuntu-Server (14.04) after I installed Apache2 and PHP5 via `apt-get`. 
My initial steps:

1. installed apache2 - `apt-get install apache2`
2. installed php5 with the usual modules `apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt ...`

Then i followed this tutorial to get pthreads running ([User contributed manual on php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/pthreads.installation.php)):

```
1 - Get PHP version
For this example we will use version: 5.4.36
# wget http://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.4.36.tar.gz

2- Get Pthreads version:
I'm using an old version but, you could take any on
# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/pthreads-1.0.0.tgz

Extract both, php and pthreads versions

#tar zxvf php-5.4.36.tar.gz
#tar zxvf pthreads-1.0.0.tgz

3- Move Pthreads to php/ext folder. Inside version of PHP downloaded at item 1.

4- Reconfigure sources
# ./buildconf --force
# ./configure --help | grep pthreads

You have to see --enable-pthreads listed. If do not, clear the buidls with this commands:

# rm -rf aclocal.m4
# rm -rf autom4te.cache/
# ./buildconf --force

5 - Inside php folder run configure command to set what we need:
# ./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads 

--prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc
6 - Install PHP
We will run make clear just to be sure that no other crashed build will mess our new one.

# make clear
# make
# make install

7 - Copy configuration file of PHP and add local lib to include path
# cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini

Edit php.ini and set Include_path to be like this:

Include_path = “/usr/local/lib/php”

9 - Check Modules
# php -m (check pthread loaded)

You have to see pthreads listed

10 - If pthread is not listed, update php.ini
# echo "extension=pthreads.so" >> /etc/php.ini
```

Everything works fine until step 7.
There is a new directory (seems to be the `make install` - outcome) in */usr/lib/php* .

Now i don't know how to handle with replacing the existing php-installation with my new one.

**Where do i have to copy the php.ini-development from step 7?**

I tried `cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini` 
but it had no effect on my existing installation.

**How can i get my new-compiled php working in / with apache2?**

I found three php.ini-files from the initial installation on my server:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in your webserver's root folder (or any folder that you can easily access from a browser). Inside the file write the following and save it as phpinfo.php:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

When you access the file from a browser, you will see the configuration of the php engine that parsed the file. Somewhere there is the path to your php.ini file, the one you need to modify.

Usually, if you are using mod_php5 then your php.ini SHOULD be the one located under the apache2 folder; if you are using php-fpm then it should be the one under fpm, but the only certain way to know which one you are using is to issue a phpinfo().